# Gomage Lightcheckout vs DPS PxFusion

Tags: magento, gomage

this is my problem. I'm using Magento Enterprise version. When using DPS PxFusion by Fooman with default checkout of magento, It worked fine. User will be redirected to success page after place order, and that order will have status as "**Processing**" on backend. But when I use DPS PxFusion by Fooman with Gomage Lightcheckout, user was redirected to **checkout/onepage/some-random-string** (e.g: **checkout/onepage/0000030034059696007d1794a4aa00ff**) and it says 404 not found. The order was then created in backend but have status as "**Pending Payment (DPS)**". No log was generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to answer you because the bug is special, it happened between two Magento modules (cost modules). Is there a way to check the function, maybe a development website?